# Problem with saving coins in Unity with PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using PlayerPrefs to save collected coins on each level. In a differences game, when an item is found, player gets one coin and it is saved with PlayerPrefs. And that coin value is used to display in Level Selection screen. The problem is when i finished the level for the first time, it displayed collected coins in Level Selection screen, when i finished it another a couple of times, the value on the Level Selection screen, stayed the same, coins did not add up:

Here is my script where i save coins with PlayerPrefs:

```
if (result.collider.CompareTag("Images"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Hit");
                    result.collider.enabled = false;
                    tmpCircle = Instantiate(krug1);
                    tmpCircle.SetActive(true);
                    tmpCircle.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, true);
                    tmpCircle.transform.position = new Vector3(result.point.x, result.point.y, result.point.z);
                    tmpCircle.transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x * 2f, transform.localScale.y * 2f, transform.localScale.z);
                    circle.Play("CircleAnim");
                    score += 1;
                    diff -= 1;
                    coins += 1;
                    score1.text = " " + score;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", coins);
                    PlayerPrefs.Save();
                    item.Play();
                }
```

And here is the script where i display the coins in LevelSelection Screen:

```
void Start()
    {
        coins.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins", 0).ToString();        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it is somewhere else in your code, you are setting your coins with each run of the level without reading it first. Every time you start the level you should read the coin data first or it will be overriden.

At the start of the level you should include

```
void Start()
{
    coins= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins", 0);        
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, i had put  `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins", 0)` at the top of Update method, that's why it didn't work